# Error 'The argument type 'bool Function(EmployeeDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool Function(SalesDetails)?' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, casting

I need to use a callback that has two classes - a base and a derived class. I need to pass that argument type as argument for a callback, I have tried using the base class as the argument type in typedef but I'm getting the following error:

```
The argument type 'bool Function(EmployeeDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool Function(SalesDetails)?'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable).
```

[image: eg]

I have tried to typecast as follows that resolves the issue:
[image: type_cast]

But I need a way to provide either of the class as an argument instead of a single base class.

Also I have tried using dynamic as argument type in typedef still it can't be resolved and shows the below error:

```
The argument type 'bool Function(SalesDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool Function(dynamic)?'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
```

Here is my completed code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

 final String title;

 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 Employee emp = Employee((SalesDetails sales) {
   EmployeeDetails emp = sales as EmployeeDetails;
   return true;
 });
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(),
     body: Container(
         child: Text(
       func(emp),
     )),
   );
 }
}

String func(Employee sales) {
 String str = 'value';
 return str;
}

typedef EmployeeCallback = bool Function(dynamic details);

class Employee {
 Employee(this.onValue);
 EmployeeCallback? onValue;
}

class SalesDetails {
 SalesDetails(this.name, this.id);
 final String name;
 final num id;
}

class EmployeeDetails extends SalesDetails {
 EmployeeDetails(this.empid, String name, num id) : super(name, id);

 final num empid;
}
```

I need to pass any of the class as argument type as mentioned below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your error is basically saying: "you provided a `bool Function(EmployeeDetails)` but you needed to provide a `bool Function(SalesDetails)?`"

Because this is an OOP question, lets use animals:

```
class Animal {
  void eat() => print('eating');
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  void bark() => print('barking');
}
```

Using these classes, your error looks like: "you provided a `bool Function(Dog)` but you needed to provide a `bool Function(Animal)?`"

This makes sense: the parameter is expecting a function that can handle any `Animal`, but you gave it one that only knows how to handle `Dog`s, for example:

```
void feedAnimals(bool Function(Animal) shouldFeed) {
  allAnimals  // a List<Animal> from somewhere else in our code
    .where(shouldFeed)
    .forEach((animal) => animal.feed());
}
```

Imagine you instead tried to pass a `bool Function(Dog)` into this:

```dart
final void Function(Dog) shouldFeedDog = (dog) => dog.tailLength > 10;
feedAnimals(shouldFeedDog);  // compile error
```

If this code didn't give a compile time error, you would try to call `.tailLength` on all the items in `allAnimals`, but not all `Animal`s have tails, so this code is unsafe.

To fix your error, you can define a `bool Function(SalesDetails)` that does what you expect:

````
final bool Function(SalesDetails) checkSalesDetails = (details) {
  // perform checking logic
};

// or 

bool checkSalesDetails(SalesDetails details) {
  // perform checking logic
}

Or, you can change the place you provide the function to be happy with a `bool Function(EmployeeDetails)`. In the animal analogy, this might look like:
```dart
void feedDogs(bool Function(Dog) shouldFeedDog) {
  allAnimals
    .whereType<Dog>()  // filter out non-Dogs, return an Iterable<Dog>
    .where(shouldFeedDog)
    .forEach((dog) => dog.feed());
}
````

Comment: Using the classes as shown above still results in the following error:  The argument type 'bool Function(EmployeeDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool Function(SalesDetails)?'. I have changed the typedef as follows using the base class type . `typedef EmployeeCallback = bool Function(SalesDetails details);`